# Using SendKeys.Send() or SendKeys.Sendwait() to send key which you have hooked:

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, sendkeys

I have hoooked Grave ascent (`) to use for some other purpose:

```
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);  
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)  
{   if (m.Msg == **0x0312**)  
..... other code ....
```

If user needs to type Grave (`) then it is available from Alt+96 from keyboard numpad.

But in the code when I try the same using:

```
SendKeys.Send("(%96)"); -Doesn't output anything  
SendKeys.Send("%(96)"); -Doesn't output anything  
SendKeys.Send("(%(96))"); -Doesn't output anything  
SendKeys.Send("\u0060"); -Throws Exception Infinite loop  
SendKeys.Send("`");
```

-Last two command throw Exception Infinite loop (as I am actually sending Grave `)

Following Group outputs Grave (`)

```
Clipboard.Clear();  
Clipboard.SetText("\u0060");  
SendKeys.Flush();  
SendKeys.Send("^v");  
SendKeys.Flush();  
Clipboard.Clear();
```

I am trying to avoid using this, as I might be destroying some vital information on Clipboard.
Kindly guide how to output (`) without using Clipboard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This cannot work of course, you'll immediately trigger the hotkey again.  You are simply using the wrong api function, you need SetWindowsHookEx() to set a low-level keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL).

Comment: Thanks for prompt revert. But, SendKeys.Send("^v"); or user pressing Alt+96 from keyboard is doing same thing, which works. I will check SetWindowsHookEx()  Thanks again.